# How to implement a recurring real-time task in SYCL

Tags: c++, gpgpu, sycl

What is the recommended way to implement a soft real-time task in SYCL?

Is it to continually re-submit operations to the command queue and the call wait (or get_access<cl::sycl::access::mode::read_write>() ) to trigger the kernel execution and buffer transfers?

It seems there should be a way to:
A) build the command queue
B) then just change contents in the input buffers
C) trigger execution
D) collect the results from output buffers
E) jump back to B)

This would not re-build the command queue each time. Is this how it is done?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the constraints you want ? If you want hard real-time (like controlling robots in environment with humans around, without harming or killing them), you won't get away without a real-time OS.

Comment: Soft real-time loop, where failure means a dropped frame or two but not a catastrophic loss of appendages. :-)

Comment: Apologies, I sloppily used real-time to infer continuous operation at a semi steady frame rate as compared what the examples all seem to be: a one shot analytical operation.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can suggest is the use of "double buffering" which uses two SYCL buffers and data is swapped between them, but there is currently no way to express a command buffer as one single thing.

For some examples I would suggest taking a look at the demos in the [ComputeCpp samples GitHub repo](https://github.com/codeplaysoftware/computecpp-sdk/).

Specifically the Game of Life and Nbody demos [use the class DoubleBuf](https://github.com/codeplaysoftware/computecpp-sdk/search?q=DoubleBuf) for swapping data in and out for processing.

Alternatively you can look at the [update loop of the Fluid demo](https://github.com/codeplaysoftware/computecpp-sdk/blob/88585fc7581abb36badd0deb3131830fd112149d/demos/fluid/fluid.h#L146) which processes data in what is a more standard way with SYCL, with multiple kernels launched on update and buffers are created each time the update loop is run.